# Different results in IE and Firefox given multiple definitions for the same selector

Tags: html, css

I have two CSS files specifying the same property for the same selector. The first file has:

```
.test{ padding: 0.3em; }
```

and the second file has:

```
.test{ padding: 3px; }
```

Internet Explorer follows the second rule, but Firefox follows the first. Is this because Firefox considers `em`s to be higher priority?

Comment: If I do a simple test on Firefox 16, the last declaration will be followed, whether it's ems or pixels. Are you sure both of your css files are being considered by Firefox ?

Comment: No difference in units would cause a higher specificity in one browser vs another.  There must be something else going on - please post **all** relevant HTML and CSS, or create a JSfiddle which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Did you try emptying the cache of both browsers?